# asp.net 5 Memory Cache not working

Tags: asp.net

Using asp.net 5 core, I am trying to use memory cache.

This [article](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/performance/caching/memory.html) suggests adding a cache dependency ("Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.0.0-rc2-final") to project.json, which doesn't work. i have tried different depency but it fails. i have also tried using nuget that also fails to install the right package.

Any suggestion would be appreciated ?

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*? Are you getting a compiler error? A runtime one, perhaps? Can you post something that'd help us identify the issue?

Comment: Also note that 1.0.0 is out, don't use RC2 version